# Ignore routing for a specific folder

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-web-api

I have an Asp.NET WebAPI project and a ReactJS app stored under `<web-root>\app`.
The react app itself is expecting a parameter passed in the URL

```
http://web-root/app/my-super-parameter.
```

How do I configure the routing in the ASP.NET app itself so it ignores that `app` folder and calls it as it is? Right now I'm getting a 404 error when calling the URL.

When creating the ReactApp I use `http://localhost:5000/my-super-parameter` and it works as needed. The time came to deploy to production under the same website as the REST project itself.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Thx

Comment: Have you tried `routes.IgnoreRoute("app/{*pathInfo}");`?

Comment: yes, getting 404 as well.